# Unable to Renew or Generate Cognitive Services v7.0 API Keys

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am creating some documentation for Microsoft Virtual Academy and am required to use the v7.0 endpoints for the documentation, labs, and videos, however there seems to be no way to renew or generate additional API Keys once a v7.0 Key has expired. The link to basically "start using a real key via Azure" only takes you to the Azure Portal, which does not currently support creating API Keys that work for v7.0 endpoints.

[image]

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Currently free trial keys for v7.0 could be requested via the Azure marketing portal from: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/.
There is “Bing Search APIs v7 PREVIEW” product under “Search” tab. 
Free trial keys will expire after 30 days from requested, and no way to extend the expiration date now.